# How to set locale for angularjs-bootstrap-datetimepicker via imported momentjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ecmascript-6, momentjs, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I use [angularjs-bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://github.com/dalelotts/angularjs-bootstrap-datetimepicker) as

```
import uiBootsrapDatetimepicker from 'angularjs-bootstrap-datetimepicker';
angula.module('myModule', [uiBootsrapDatetimepicker])
```

and Webpack for bundling.

I want to set a custom locale (or how to change a first day of the week?) and I found in [readme](https://github.com/dalelotts/angularjs-bootstrap-datetimepicker#i18n--l10n-support):

> All internationalization is handled by Moment.js, see Moment's documentation for details. In most cases, all that is needed is a call to moment.locale(String)

But how if there is import new momentjs instance in code
([GitHub url](https://github.com/dalelotts/angularjs-bootstrap-datetimepicker/blob/master/src/js/datetimepicker.js#L18)):

```
var mt = typeof moment === 'undefined' ? require('moment') : moment
```

end then in code there ([GitHub url](https://github.com/dalelotts/angularjs-bootstrap-datetimepicker/blob/master/src/js/datetimepicker.js#L489)):

```
moment.locale().toLowerCase()
```

Where can I set a locale for Moment if this one creates within another module?

Answer (score 2):

Include moment.js and angular-moment in your document:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment-with-locales.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-moment/1.2.0/angular-moment.js"></script>
```

Add angularMoment to your app:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ng-bootstrap-datepicker', 'angularMoment']);
```

Then you can call `moment` in your controller:

```
var AppCtrl = function ($scope){
    moment.locale("fr");
    console.log(moment.locale());
};
```

Comment: The problem is that external module imports Moment itself and uses only default locale. Or uses global 'moment' variable that I don't have in my case (es6 imports + webpack).

Comment: I don't know a lot about webpack, but couldn't you do something like this? `import moment from 'moment'; window.moment = moment;` to add it to the global scope, and then use `myAngularApp.value('moment', moment);` to inject it into your app?

Comment: I have another bundle for libraries and can't mutate their globals. So I hacked lib src for now(